# jQuery Masked Input Plugin: Wrong cursor position in Phone Masking

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mask

I am using jQuery plugin (jquery.mask.js-v1.14.10) to mask phone numbers in a format:- **(000) 000-0000**.

I am using below jQuery code:-

```
$("body").on("input propertychange", ".USMobileFormat", function (e) {            
            $(this).attr('maxlength', '14');
            $(this).mask('(000) 000-0000');
 });
```

When I enter first digit, mouse cursor comes before that entered digit.

Ex:- Suppose my phone number is 586**** , here 1st digit is 5 and I entered it then cursor comes before 5 thus it creates a problem when I enter 2nd digit which is 8 here, so my entered number would be "(85".

I am facing one more problem:- When I replace 2nd last digit of phone number cursor goes to last position of text-box(supposed to be at 2nd last position), which is also wrong. TIA.

Comment: facing same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Easy example below. i have use Ace-Admin theme jquery phone mask.
You can open the link save it , use as local

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<input class="form-control input-sm input-mask-phone valid" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" type="text" value="">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ace.jeka.by/assets/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.mask.definitions['~'] = '[+-]';
        $('.input-mask-phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');
    });
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```